# Posted raw data to restController become null

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, postman

I have found some simillar questions, but couldn't find an answer that works for me.

The problem is when I post data from Postman, in the controller I get null values,

[image: Postman request/response]

here is the controller :

```
@RestController
public class LoginPageController extends AbstractPageContoller{

    @RequestMapping(value="login",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public LoginForm login(@RequestBody LoginForm loginForm) {
        System.err.println(loginForm.getLogin());
        return loginForm;
    }
}
```

and here is the class that I try to send as data to the controller :

```
public class LoginForm{

    private String login;
    private String password;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input data is wrong:
it should be:

`{ "login" : "aaa", "password" : "aaa" }`